# Ubuntu 20.04 not recognising a new optical drive

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb, optical

I am completely fed up with the noise and repeated glitches on my old built-in optical drive so I bought a Froibetz pop-up mobile external dvd-rw reader.

This connects via USB3 or Channel C and claims to be Linux Chrome compatible (isn't that Linux?) When I connect up both via USB 3.0 and C - it is now at least being recognised but when I go to play a track on Audacious it stalls at first track. I get message:

Error playing cdda://sr1/Track%201.wav:
Error reading metadata

I suspect I need to install a driver but unsure how to start doing that. Any help would be welcome. I run Ubuntu 20.04 and don't have windows installed.

Comment: All drives are "Linux compatible". And when connected nothing happens (unless you feed it a disk). The clicking noise however suggests it isn't getting enough power. Make sure you're connecting to a USB3.x port as USB2.0 is often not enough as most drives I know require an additional connector (power only) to another USB2.0 port.

Comment: My own external drive was properly recognized only after a reboot.

Comment: Do you have Windows installed? If so, does it work there? The drive is only compatible with "MacBook Apple OS Laptop/Desktops/Win 10/7/8.1/ Linux Chrome"... it doesn't say Linux compatible. The clicking noise my indicate a hardware problem with the drive... is the laser lens dirty?

Comment: Are you sure the audio CD is not scratched?